# AWS SSL certificate with Elastic Beanstalk: HTTPS site not reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group, aws-acm

When I associate an AWS certificate with my Elastic Beanstalk app and visit the domain using https, I get 'This site can’t be reached, mydomain.com refused to connect.'  I can visit the site using http.

I created a security certificate with AWS's ACM.  I added my domain name, example.com, along with additional names that were sub domains to the certificate.  In my app's environment 'Loading balancing' section I set this up:

[image]

I setup the SecurityGroup named `awseb-e-abc123-stack-*` for my environment as follows:
[image]

There is another security group named `awseb-e-abc123-stack-AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup-*`, which is as follows.  It has the same name tag as the above group, which is the same as my environment name:

[image]

It seems, though, that the entries of the "AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup" security group does nothing, as removing all the entries still allows HTTP traffic to work.

In `.elasticbeanstalk\securelistener.config`, I have the following

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    SSLCertificateId: <my certificate's ARN>
    ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
    InstancePort: 80
```

It seems, though, if I add a syntax error in this file, the deployment still succeeds.

Here is the output of `curl -vL https://<my domain>`:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://<my domain>/
*   Trying <my elastic IP>...
* connect to <my elastic IP> port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to <my domain> port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <my domain> port 443: Connection refused
```

I used a separate domain name register to setup my domain name, and set up my domain's DNS A records IP address equal to my Elastic IP.

**[edit]**

I had mentioned above that changing the rules of the load balancer security group does nothing.  This was because my EC2 instances's security group was pointing to the instance's security group, not the security group of the load balancer.  When I pointed the EC2's security group to the load balancer's security group, the security group's rules are execercized.  I verified this by removing all the rules from the load balancer security group, and seeing that no requests are accepted.  However, if I add back the HTTP and HTTPS rules to the load balancer security group but remove all the rules from the instance security group, all HTTP requests are going through.  This is NOT expected behavior because the load balancer is supposed to forward traffic to the instance.  What seems to be happening is (1) the instance and load balancer security groups are not at all related to the instance and load balancer and (2) no traffic is going to the load balancer.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

**[edit 2]**

I misread gkrizek's comment.  If I use the public DNS of the load balancer, I am able connect using either HTTP or HTTPS.  I am able to connect to both versions using telnet.  So instead of creating an A record that set testdomain.com to my Elastic IP, I created a sub.testdomain.com CNAME record set to the load balancer.  Now I am able to browse to both `http://sub.testdomain.com` and `https://sub.testdoamin.com`.  Two questions:

- Is it OK to use the load balancer's public DNS in the CNAME record?  I can't use the *.elasticbeanstalk.com URL because it could change, so I'm wondering if the same situation applies here
- How can I secure `https://testdomain.com` (no sub domain).  It seems like with this method, it is impossible to have `https://testdomain.com` since I cannot create an A record with an domain name.

Comment: Do you terminate https at the load balancer, and continue the request with http? What happens when you do a curl request like `curl -vL --insecure $url`?

Comment: Doesn't AWS by default terminate the HTTPS at the load balancer by default?  How can I determine whether this is the case?

Comment: I'm not to sure if there is a default (if there was it would probably be to  terminate). You can check by making sure the traffic going to the instances is unencrypted (that is the instance can understand what it is receiving), or by checking that the load balancer is sending information to the instances as "http", rather than "https".

Comment: How do I check whether the traffic is going unencrypted to the instances?

Comment: Normally you can check if an application, on the instance, can understand the can understand the traffic, it won't understand encrypted requests.

Comment: With `curl -vL` it should resolve the url to a particular AWS load balancer. Then the load balancer should forward it you an instance. Can you confirm that the url you are using points to an AWS load balancer, or forwards the request to an AWS load balancer? In your curl output it you says the url you provide resolves to the "my elastic IP". Normally you have elastic IP addresses associated with an EC2 instance, and it looks like the instances 443 port isn't open.

Comment: Have you tried loading the DNS name of the load balancer in your browser? Also, can you try to telnet to the DNS of the load balancer on port 443? That would at least remove DNS issues with your custom domain/cert from the equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you have to create a CNAME record with your domain and use the load balancer DNS name as the address.  If you use the Elastic IP, the requests will not go to the load balancer.

To answer my last questions:

- [AWS says](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html) this is OK
- You cannot directly do this because AWS does not allow you to assign an Elastic IP to a load balancer. What you can do is have a URL record that redirects testdomain.com to https://www.testdomain.com